# Coded UI Tests - Is it possible to get InnerText from HtmlIFrame?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to validate that the correct content has been loaded in an iFrame via Coded UI Tests. The problem is that the InnerText is not populated when fetching the iFrame-element:

```
HtmlIFrame iframe = new HtmlIFrame(parent);
var innerText = iframe.InnerText; // Null
```

So is there any way of getting the innerText from an iframe-object?

Comment: Are you able to find iframe ?

Answer (score -1):

Find the Immediate Div or Table Element after HtmlIFrame and use InnerText Property for Div/Table Element, now you can find the desired output.